# How to redirect a url only with specific parameters in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I have a url that looks like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/page.aspx?code=1.a
```

I want to redirect this URL via IIS to:

```
www.mywebsite.com/page.aspx?code=1.b
```

I would like to do this through IIS and not within the code.

I have various other website urls that look like:

```
www.mywebsite.com/page.aspx?code=2
www.mywebsite.com/page.aspx?code=3.a
www.mywebsite.com/page.aspx?code=6.c
```

I don't want these to be affected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this in IIS 7.5 is to install the **URL Rewrite extension** from Microsoft into IIS.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Once you have it installed, you can just add a rule to redirect from `?code=1.a` to `?code=1.b`. In IIS, you'll see a new entry called `URL Rewrite` under the `IIS` heading for your website. You can use the editor there to create a new rule. Once the rule is created, it will be written into your `web.config` file.

In the `web.config` file, the rule should look something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Code=1.a redirect" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" 
                  stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="page.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="page.aspx?code=1.b"
                        appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="code=1.a" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```