# URL rewriting based on input url

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a web application written in asp.net webforms 4.0

The site has about 20 aspx.net pages and 30 controls. If you go to `www.mysite.com` the default page is `www.mysite.com/challenge.aspx`.

if a user types in

```
www.mysite.com/JohnDoe
```

I need it to go to

```
www.mysite.com/JohnDoe/challenge
```

I am looking for something like `www.mysite.com/{0}/challenge.aspx`

This name will be what tells the application what Connection string to use.

Comment: What is your application server? If you are using Apache, you can use the mod-rewrite module.

Comment: You can try to integrate some Url rewriting library to your website like 

http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Do you want the user to be redirected or simply use a default page?

Comment: You could use the UrlRewrite extension from Microsoft. There's a link to the download and a sample web.config setup in my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771824/how-to-redirect-a-url-only-with-specific-parameters-in-iis/15772754#15772754